# Gameobject.find only returning null even when gameobject is active in heirarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am trying to tranfer from one scene to another and trigger a function once this happens.
So when i press my play game button on my main menu page it loads a function to begin building the world. I have got the function to build a world but once ive attatched it to a button it has stopped working.
So far I believe this is down to me not fully understanding the method of calling a function from another class for it to run normally.
I begin to define my GameObject as:

```
private static GameOjbect Play;
```

This doesnt allow me to assign a GameObject to it within the unity editor. Therefore, i went down the method of using:

```
GameObject Play = GameObject.Find("PlayScreen");
```

My GameObeject is active in the heirarchy when this function begins but the program still does not function correctly. To test where the program is encountering an issue I used:

```
Debug.Log(Play);
```

Which i believed would just output "PlayScreen" to the debug log as this is the gameobject I am searching for, but this only returns "Null" and my program does not progress any further which is creating a wall.

Below is my main menu code:

```
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject PlayScene;
    public GameObject SettingsScreen;

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("InGame");
        Debug.Log("Loading startup...");
        WorldBuilder.Awake();
    }
}
```

Below is my WorldBuilding function:

```
public class WorldBuilder:MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static GameObject Play;

    public static void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Finding Scene...");
        GameObject Play = GameObject.Find("PlayScreen");
        Debug.Log(Play);
    } 
}
```

How come my program is not finding the GameObject? 
I am still new to C# so any sort of help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: I dont understand why you need to call `Awake` from another function. `Awake` will be called when you load new scene anyway and can you also check in `Update` if  `GameObject Play = GameObject.Find("PlayScreen")` finds the object. Then we can know if it is a synchronization problem or not.

Comment: @AliKanat Okay so i put it in Update and it worked. However, is there a way to get this to work without continuously repeating this in the update function?

Comment: You normally should do it in `Awake` or `Start` but you don't have to call it from previous scene like you do with `WorldBuilder.Awake()` just try doing it in the loaded scene with a non-static `Awake()` you see it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the Awake function static. If you do Unity won't call it. 
Also, you are creating a **local** variable when you do `GameObject Play = GameObject.Find("PlayScreen");`. If you want to keep it in a static variable, you shouldn't do that. See below:

```
public class WorldBuilder : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameObject Play;

    public static void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Finding Scene...");
        WorldBuilder.Play = GameObject.Find("PlayScreen");
        Debug.Log(Play);
    } 
}
```

Also, remove the call in PlayGame:

```
public void PlayGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("InGame");
    Debug.Log("Loading startup...");
}
```